# How to shuffle the data in each of the columns of a PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, shuffle, databricks

I'm a beginner in programming with PySpark. I have the following data in a CSV file which is being read into a Spark Dataframe and I would like to generate a large dataset starting from a small one.

[image]

```
# read the csv file in a spark dataframe
df = (spark.read
       .option("inferSchema", "true")
       .option("header", "true")
       .csv(file_path))
```

I want to shuffle the data in each of the columns i.e. 'InvoiceNo', 'StockCode', 'Description'respectively as shown below in snapshot.

[image]

The below code was implemented to orderBy column values randomly:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.orderBy("InvoiceNo", rand()).show(10)
```

I'm not getting the correct output even after executing the above. Can anyone help in solving the problem? This link was also referred : [Randomly shuffle column in Spark RDD or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287543/randomly-shuffle-column-in-spark-rdd-or-dataframe) but the code mentioned is throwing an error.

Answer (score 4):

The PySpark `rand` function can be used to create a column of random values on your dataframe. The dataframe can then be ordered by the new column to produce the randomised order e.g.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand

df.withColumn('rand', rand(seed=42)).orderBy('rand')
```

To randomise the order of each column individually, create a Dataframe for each column separately and randomise that, each with a unique seed e.g.

```
col_1_df = df.select('col_1').withColumn('rand', rand(seed=seed_1)).orderBy('rand')
col_2_df = df.select('col_2').withColumn('rand', rand(seed=seed_2)).orderBy('rand')
```

To recompose a Dataframe with the original columns, you could add a row number and then join on that e.g.

```
window = Window().orderBy(lit('A'))
col_1_with_row_num = col_1_df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window))
col_2_with_row_num = col_2_df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window))

col_1_with_row_num.join(col_2_with_row_num, on=['row_num']).select('col_1', 'col_2').show()
```

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: This is not giving the correct solution. The randomization is getting done on the dataframe row object and not on separate dataframe columns which is the intended goal.

Comment: Individual column shuffle and recombination added.

Comment: Is there a specific need to add a column with row_num? Can we not do it without the same?

Comment: There may be other ways to recombine the dataframes, using a row_num column is one way.

Comment: I think the question would benefit from explaining why you want to do, what seems like, an usual thing i.e. break the integrity of each row by shuffling each column like a slot machine.

Comment: I'm looking out for a way to generate large dataset having a small dataset in hand.

Comment: I recommend you explain that in your question, for others that find it.

Comment: Done. Although, I have mentioned in the beginning of the question that I'm new to concepts of Spark.