# Merge multiple Dataframes into one Dataframe in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario where I am getting columns from 10 sources and each in form of dataframes(i.e. df1,df2,df3 .... df10) with one row value.Each dataframes has different set of Columns nothing in common. I need to Merge the Dataframes without using JOIN.

**For Example :**

DataFrame (df1) {Columns : age}:

```
12
```

DataFrame (df2) {Columns : height}:

```
4.8
```

Resultant DataFrame (rdf) {Columns : age,height}:

```
2,3.2
```

Comment: You need a union.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882529/how-to-zip-twoor-more-dataframe-in-spark