# How to merge 3 dataframes (with no common column) column-wise in scala?

Tags: scala, dataframe

I have 3 dataframes, all having different columns. I want to merge all the dataframes to a single dataframe (which will have all the columns contained in 3 individual dataframes). I am using scala for this. How should I proceed.?

Comment: What is data frame? Do you use spark?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zip two(or more) DataFrame in Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882529/how-to-zip-twoor-more-dataframe-in-spark)