# Apache Spark SQL - Multiple arrays explode and 1:1 mapping

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am pretty new to Apache Spark SQL and trying to achieve the following. I have the following DF which I want to convert to a intermediate DF and then to json.

```
array [a,b,c,d,e] and  array [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Need them to be

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Tried the explode option but I get only one array exploded.

Thanks for the assistance..

Comment: maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32884253/2129801) helps

Comment: hello @sarashan did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 2):

To join two dataframes in Spark you will need to use a common column which exists on both dataframes and since you don't have one you need to create it. Since version 1.6.0 Spark supports this functionality through [monotonically_increasing_id](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#monotonically_increasing_id())() function. The next code illustrates this case:

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import spark.implicits._

    val df = Seq("a","b","c","d","e")
      .toDF("val1")
      .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)

    val df2 = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      .toDF("val2")
      .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)

    df.join(df2, "id").select($"val1", $"val2").show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+----+
|val1|val2|
+----+----+
|a   |1   |
|b   |2   |
|c   |3   |
|d   |4   |
|e   |5   |
+----+----+
```

Good luck