# How to stack several 1 x 1 dataframes to get a 1 x n dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a huge dataframe containing millions of rows. From these rows I derive new `k` dataframes which have only 1 row and 1 column. 
What's a good way to concatenate these k dataframes together so as to now get a a dataframe `1 x k` that has 1 row and k columns.

1. In the past I started with using a crossJoin among all the `k` dataframes, such as 
   `df1.crossJoin(df2).crossJoin(df3).crossJoin(dfk)`

   This resulted in a broadcast timeout error,
2. Later I moved to what I thought is a smarter solutions.

   `df1.withColumn("temp_id", lit(0)).join(df2.withColumn("temp_id", lit(0)), "temp_id").drop("temp_id")`.

   This resulted in a weirder yet similar error of broadcast timeout.

The result that I really want is a new DataFrame with 1 row and k columns which in numpy/pandas language could be

`pandas.concat(..., axis=1)`
OR
`np.vstack(.....)`

Comment: pd.concat would be my guess, but without any data it is hard to determine the best way.

Comment: Keeping in mind that the main difference of pandas and spark is that the last one is a distributed system the errors you mentioned might be a result of a big shuffle. Please provide a full description as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples

Answer (score 0):

The operation I think you want to perform is a "zip" operation. Spark does not provide this method for Dataframes, but you can see how it works with the following example (A Spark version follows this example):

```scala
scala> val l1 = List("a", "b")
l1: List[String] = List(a, b)

scala> val l2 = List(1,2)
l2: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> val zipped = l1.zip(l2)
zipped: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,2))

scala> zipped.foreach(println)
(a,1)
(b,2)

scala>
```

How to do this in Spark has already been answered here:
[How to zip two (or more) DataFrame in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882529/how-to-zip-two-or-more-dataframe-in-spark)

Basically, you do this:

```scala
val zippedRDD = df1.rdd.zip(df2.rdd)
```

this will leave you with an RDD, which you can convert to a DF or DS as needed in the usual way.

Comment: @praateek if this has helped you, could you please accept the answer (click on the grey check mark next to the answer) and upvote it? Thanks.