# How to transform two data-frames into a List of Tuples of Rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, user-defined-functions

I have a list of tuple of numbers which brings the data from the dataframe. I extract the data from the dataframe which corresponds to the numbers(SNO). I want to pass that data into a function which accepts Row as a parameter.
I am thinking to convert that dataframe into List of tuple of Rows => List(Tuple2(Row, Row))
So that I can pass those rows into a function in interative basis.
Any efficient method would e appreciated.
Imagine I have 
`val list0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2),(5,4),(3,6))`
& I have two sample dataframe

```
+-------+-----+-------+
|Country| Item|groupNo|
+-------+-----+-------+
|  India|mango|      1|
|  India|Apple|      5|
|  India| musk|      3|
+-------+-----+-------+
```

and another dataframe is like

```
+-------+-----+-------+
|Country| Item|groupNo|
+-------+-----+-------+
|  India| musk|      2|
|  India|mango|      6|
|  India|mango|      4|
+-------+-----+-------+
```

So I want result like

```
List((Row(India,mango,1), Row(India,musk,2)), (Row(India,Apple,5), Row(India,mango,4)), etc...)
```

So that I can pass that List(Tuple2(Row, Row)) to a certain function as it is.

Comment: Could you please share whatever code you have tried.

Comment: Maybe you could also add some example data (input and expected output)? This would make your question easier to understand

Comment: Hi @werner, I have shared sample code to you. Hope it helps to understand. If anything comes in your mind ask me or any efficient idea you have. Share then

Comment: does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32884253/2129801) answer your question?